# Communications link failure when execute a procedure in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, procedure, socketexception

I hava a web server with mysql, some configuration belows:

```
mysql: mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.95, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
spring: 3.05
mysql-driver:5.1.13
```

This exception came out first time was about `2013-12-13 02:33`, then I do somethings:
1, add `autoReconnect=true` to mysql url;
2, add `<property name="houseKeepingTestSql" value="select CURRENT_DATE"></property>` to ProxoolDataSource configuratin.

I thought the bug was fixed, but I am wrong, this exception appeared again, and almost at the same time(2013-12-16 02:33).

this is stack trace:

```
The last packet successfully received from the server was 131,609 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 2 milliseconds ago.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_41]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_41]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) ~[na:1.6.0_41]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) ~[na:1.6.0_41]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1118) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3055) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2941) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3489) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2113) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1364) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.execute(CallableStatement.java:879) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor121.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_41]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_41]
        at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.ProxyStatement.invoke(ProxyStatement.java:100) ~[proxool-0.9.1.jar:na]
        at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.ProxyStatement.intercept(ProxyStatement.java:57) ~[proxool-0.9.1.jar:na]
        at $java.sql.Wrapper$$EnhancerByProxool$$df6af44.execute(<generated>) ~[proxool-cglib.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_41]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_41]
        at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.PreparedStatementLogger.invoke(PreparedStatementLogger.java:58) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.execute(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.CallableStatementHandler.query(CallableStatementHandler.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:70) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:57) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:267) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:141) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:105) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:81) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:101) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:95) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:59) ~[mybatis-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor91.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_41]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_41]
        at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:355) ~[mybatis-spring-1.1.1.jar:1.1.1]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_41]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129) ~[na:1.6.0_41]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2499) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar:na]
```

And always the procedure `querprize()` throw this exception, others query seems normal.
could you help me to fix this?
Thanks ahead.

**Edit**
I have fix this problem, At 2:33 am, mysql on this server was backing up data, so much `I/O` operation was running , and the `maxActiveConnectionTime` in my project was just 120000 miliseconds.
The Proxool datasource closed current connection before the procedure finished and returned, that why the `Socket closed` exception happened in this situation. So my solution is set the `maxActiveConnectionTime` much longger.

Comment: [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2840358/1031945). [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2985169/1031945)

Comment: Are MySQL and your application running on the same host?

Comment: No, they are on different server.

Comment: Is `querprize()` a MySQL stored procedure, or a Java method?  If the former, have you tried calling it from outside of Java (e.g. the MySQL command line tool?  If the latter, might we see it?

Comment: Are you sure the server did not reboot and sever the socket connection? Check `uptime`.

Comment: Are you sure your query isn't just exploding into something that will take over 2 minutes to complete somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at [this](http://itellity.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/mysql-reconnect-issues-or-the-last-packet-successfully-received-from-the-server-xx-milliseconds-ago-errors/)

it would seem that in addition to the `autoReconnect=true` url appendage, the following properies would help:

if you use DBCP as connection pool in Spring, add the following          entries to your datasource definition

```
<bean id="datasource" destroy-method="close">
<property name="driverClassName” value="${.jdbc.driver}" />
<property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
<property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
<property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
<property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />  <--- This
<property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />         <---- and this
</bean>
```

if you use c3p0 as connection pool in Spring, add the following entries to your datasource definition

```
<bean id=”pooledDataSource” class=”com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource” destroy-method=”close”>

<property name=”driverClass” value=”${driver}”></property>
<property name=”jdbcUrl” value=”${url}” />
<property name=”user” value=”${username}” />
<property name=”password” value=”${password}” />
<property name=”initialPoolSize” value=”20″ />
<property name=”minPoolSize” value=”10″ />
<property name=”maxPoolSize” value=”50″ />
<property name=”checkoutTimeout” value=”1000″ />
<property name=”maxStatements” value=”500″ />
<property name=”testConnectionOnCheckin” value=”false” />   <---- this
<property name=”testConnectionOnCheckout” value=”true” />   <-    and this
<property name=”maxIdleTime” value=”1800″ />
<property name=”idleConnectionTestPeriod” value=”1000″ />
</bean>
```